# Changing branch protection policy while pull request is still open

Tags: azure-devops

I am wondering how AZ DevOps is handling the case that before Pull Request creation let's say branch policy A is configured. Then after some time (while the pull request is not closed yet) the branch protection policy is changed to B. Which policy is now enforced in the mentioned pull request?

One small addition we want to change the policy via Azure CLI.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy that was in place when the PR started holds true.  We've made changes to our policies while PRs were open as well.  To get them to take the new policy, we took them back to draft and then re-published the pr.  It then took on the new policy.

Comment: Ok thanks. What I also figured out while testing is that if a new commit is created in the source branch of the PR after the policy has been changed then the new policy is automatically applied to the PR.
Is that a feature or a bug? For me this sounds more like a feature.

Comment: Feature; as the old policy doesn't exist any more.  The policies are applied upon a change to the PR (new push, draft/publish, etc.). So when the change happens, the PR looks for any policies that would apply to it and then execute them.

Answer (score 0):

> Which policy is now enforced in the mentioned pull request?

The short answer is, from the moment you modify the policy to **B**, all PRs that **are or will be** in active status will be bound by the new policy(`policy B`). Because the old policy definition does not exists any more.

You can take the method that M.ob mentioned above to make the active PR take the new policy for ensure. But in most cases, you don't need to do this. After you modify the policy, PR will be automatically constrained by the system, even if you don't refresh the page/PR.